# OpenGL texture not appearing as defined

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm setting up a hard-coded texture to use as a debug texture for my OpenGL application.  The function that defines it is:

```
void Texture::initDebugTexture(void)
{
    unsigned char pixels[] = {
        255, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 255,
        255, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 255
    };

    debug.loadPixels(2, 2, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    debug.setFiltering(GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

where `loadPixels` expands to:

```
void Texture::loadPixels(int width, int height, GLenum colorFormat, GLenum type, void* pixels)
{
    clean();

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colorFormat, width, height, 0, colorFormat, type, pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
}
```

and `setFiltering` is simply:

```
void Texture::setFiltering(GLenum filterMin, GLenum filterMag, float aniso = 0.0f)
{
    bind();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filterMin);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filterMag);
    if (aniso != 0.0f)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, aniso);
}
```

In `initDebugTexture`, I try to create a simple 2x2 texture with a magenta/cyan checkered pattern, so that it can never be mistaken for a real texture.  Unfortunately, that's not what happens, instead I get this:

[image: Obviously Incorrect Coloration]

What's happening here?  That peach-colored part is very odd, where could it have come from?

Comment: What are your `u/v`s? What happens when you use repeated textures, e.g. `u/v`s from 0.0 to 4.0? Is automatic mipmap generation disabled? Do you get any GL errors? What happens if you specify each single pixel diffently (red, blue, green, grey)?

Comment: When I set the colors to [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0)], I end up with: white in the upper left quadrant, cyan in the upper right, red in lower left, green in lower right.  When I set the uv's to range from 0 to 4 instead of 0 to 1, it wraps around 4 times as expected.

Comment: I assume it wraps around 4 times with wrong but consistently wrong colors. Obviously colors are being mixed. Likely in the `glTexImage2D` step. Have you tried GL_RGBA? Are `pixels` being read in a different order than you expect it? Or out-of-bounds?

Comment: For what it's worth, your `pixels` array wouldn't produce a checkerboard - it would produce a magenta stripe and a cyan stripe. You need to swap 2 of the pixels.

Comment: Try explcitly setting the internal format to GL_RGBA8, rather than using the colorFormat parameter for both values.  Also, make sure you're unbinding the texture after you've initialized it.  If you're leaving it bound some other method may be using texture functionality and impacting it.

Comment: I set the color to [(255, 0, 255, 255), (0, 255, 255, 255), (0, 255, 255, 255), (255, 0, 255, 255)] and changed the color format to GL_RGBA.  It works as intended now.

Answer (score 3):

Althouh you have mentioned how you worked around the issue in the comments already, I think I can explain what went wrong here:

I ignored the alignmet. By default, the GL expects each row to be align on a 4 byte boundary, so the data the GL actually read was not what you expected and

```
[255, 0, 255], [0, 255, 255], [255,0,255], [0,255,255]
```

became

```
[255, 0, 255], [0, 255, 255], ___ ___ [255, 0, 255] [255, U, U]
```

(with `U`meaning undefined).

Either, correctly align the data to what the GL expects, or set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` via [`glPixelStore`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPixelStore.xhtml):

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

before you specify the texture data.